# Guide to set-up DNS and Multiple domain on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dns, webserver, vps

I would like to know, how  to set-up a DNS server and to run multiple websites on a single VPS server. I already have a VPS server and I've installed webmin for my ease.. I'm still confused how to set it up.

If I can set up both of them, I know how to change the NS record in the domain registrar. So, please advise me how to do or may be a clear guide to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

You should try looking at this site for info on how to configure your web server. I don't agree with some of the steps and choices but it's a good start.

[The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Apache2, BIND, Dovecot, ISPConfig 3)](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

there are 2 software which i know, EHCP and bind9!

this is a very nice guide how to setup a web server to host multiple domains!
[Set Up Ubuntu Server With EHCP (LAMP, DNS, FTP, Mail)](http://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-ubuntu-server-with-ehcp-lamp-dns-ftp-mail)

another good tutorial:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Host-Your-Own-Domain-With-Bind9-on-Ubuntu-49585.shtml

Comment: Second link you mentioned will give me some idea to get through. Here's what I actually needed. I have a VPS & I need to host multiple domains by having my own name servers. DNS even I can use google dns to forward traffic in that case. I'm still stcuk.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.